# Start couchpotato.py at boot, without needing to leave ssh session open. ReadyNAS (Debian 7)

Tags: python, linux, debian

I need this command to run automatically on boot or when told to. At the moment i need to run the command in SSH and leave the session open, otherwise it stops.

python CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py

This is on a ReadyNAS (Debian 7)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to create it as a service. Take a look in /etc/init.d and you will find scripts that run as services. Copy one and modify it so that it calls your python script. An good example could be the init script used for starting the avahi daemon. Now, you can use 'service couchPotato start/stop/status', etc. It will also start the service automatically at boot time if the server ever reboots. Find a simple file to use as your template and google init scripts for further assistance. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with that, I'll give it a go shortly, another question: I was wondering if you could help me a little bit.
I have installed utorrent server for Debian 7 x64, through ssh commandline on my ReadyNAS 314 OS6.1.8

To start utorrent server, i need to run this command from ssh
utserver -settingspath /apps/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/

How can I get it to auto start at the unit's boot, I have seen some scripts to be put in etc/init.d
But I have tried serveral times and I never works

Your help would be much appreciated, Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 0):

From this [page](https://couchpota.to/#linux):

> - To run on boot copy the init script. `sudo cp CouchPotatoServer/init/ubuntu /etc/init.d/couchpotato`
> - Change the paths inside the init script. `sudo nano /etc/init.d/couchpotato`
> - Make it executable. `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/couchpotato`
> - Add it to defaults. `sudo update-rc.d couchpotato defaults`

`CouchPotatoServer/init/ubuntu` can be found [here](https://github.com/RuudBurger/CouchPotatoServer/tree/master/init)

`sudo update-rc.d <service> <runlevels>` is the official Debian way of inserting a service at startup. Its manpage can be read [there](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=update-rc.d).

my 2 cents,

Answer (score 0):

Use chkconfig to add the service and specify the run level. Google will give you all you need for examples of how to do this. Good luck.